# Sum Javascript multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I have problem again with javascript, i want to ask how to sum from fields?
where is the problem?
I am trying to sum all my fields using `getElementsByName` and `getElementsById`. I want to show total sum of values entered in sub total input boxes in next input box named total without refreshing page. 
Can anyone will help me to figure it out..?
Here my code

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.input', function() {
  var num1 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.input:first').val();
  var num2 = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.input:last').val();
  $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.sub-total').val(to_rupiah(num1 * num2));

  var arr = document.getElementsByName('.sub-total');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('TotalBayar').value = tot;
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 2;
  $("#addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input1" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input2" id="input2" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" onblur="findTotal()" value="" id="output" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td></tr>');
    index++;
  });
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});

function to_rupiah(angka) {
  var rev = parseInt(angka, 10).toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  var rev2 = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
    rev2 += rev[i];
    if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0 && i !== (rev.length - 1)) {
      rev2 += '.';
    }
  }
  return 'Rp. ' + rev2.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class='table table-bordered' id='customFields'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:35px;'>#</th>
      <th style='width:210px;'>Nama Barang</th>
      <th style='width:120px;'>Harga</th>
      <th style='width:75px;'>Qty</th>
      <th style='width:125px;'>Sub Total</th>
      <th style='width:40px;'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control input" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" value="" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control input" id="input2" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" id="output" onblur="findTotal()" type="text"></td>
      <td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class='alert alert-info TotalBayar'>
  <button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Baris Baru (F7)</button>
  <h2>Total : <span id='TotalBayar'>0</span></h2>
```

Please Help

Comment: You don't have any `name=".sub-total"`, so what do you expect `getElementsByName(".sub-total")` to return?

Comment: You have `class="sub-total"`, you should use jQuery `$(".sub-total").each()` to loop over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName(".sub-total")` looks for elements with `name=".sub-total"`, but you don't have that, it's a class. You can use `$(".sub-total")` to get these elements and loop over them.

```
document.getElementById('TotalBayar').value = tot;
```

won't work because `TotalBayar` is a DIV, and `.value` is only valid for inputs. Use `$("#TotalBayar").text(tot)` to set its contents.

You also can't just call `parseInt()` on the value in the sub-total fields, because they begin with `Rp.`. I've used a regular expression to get the number out of the value.

BTW, instead of `.parents("tr:first")` you can use `.closest("tr")`.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.input', function() {
  var num1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.input:first').val();
  var num2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.input:last').val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.sub-total').val(to_rupiah(num1 * num2));

  var arr = document.getElementsByName('.sub-total');
  var tot = 0;
  $(".sub-total").each(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val().match(/\d+/)[0]);
    if (val) {
      tot += val;
    }
  });
  $('#TotalBayar').text(tot);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 2;
  $("#addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input1" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control input input2" id="input2" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" onblur="findTotal()" value="" id="output" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td></tr>');
    index++;
  });
  $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});

function to_rupiah(angka) {
  var rev = parseInt(angka, 10).toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  var rev2 = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
    rev2 += rev[i];
    if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0 && i !== (rev.length - 1)) {
      rev2 += '.';
    }
  }
  return 'Rp. ' + rev2.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class='table table-bordered' id='customFields'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:35px;'>#</th>
      <th style='width:210px;'>Nama Barang</th>
      <th style='width:120px;'>Harga</th>
      <th style='width:75px;'>Qty</th>
      <th style='width:125px;'>Sub Total</th>
      <th style='width:40px;'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control input" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" value="" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control input" id="input2" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control sub-total" name="sub_total[]" id="output" onblur="findTotal()" type="text"></td>
      <td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class='alert alert-info TotalBayar'>
  <button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i> Baris Baru (F7)</button>
  <h2>Total : <span id='TotalBayar'>0</span></h2>
```